# What function gets maximized on the face of a polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

Given a polyhedron defined by a set of inequalities, I was asked to find a function that gets its maximum along one of the faces of the polyhedron. I calculated the normal to the face and said that was the function. Is it correct? Intuitively, it seems so to me. The follow-up question asked what function gets maximized along an intersection of two faces - I think it could be a linear combination of the normal vectors of those faces, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct for the first, and the answer for the first will also work for the second. You would need to take a positive linear combination for the second part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will any positive combination suffice?

Comment: Yes, any direction in the convex cone generated by the normals will do.

Comment: Wait wait wait. The normal is a vector, not a function.

Comment: You are correct - I meant that if the normal is $(1, 2, 3)$ then the function will be $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3$.. I neglected to say this was all in $R^3$